# how do i access wd elements 2 tb external hard drive from my lenovo y50 running ubuntu 15.04 64 bit

Tags: hard-drive, laptop

i just got this external hard drive but for some reason whenever i plug it into my computer, Ubuntu doesn't recognize it. however, when i switch over to windows, my laptop can recognize it just fine

Answer (score 1):

If you mean that you can put media on the drive from windows then you have already formatted otherwise do that.

If you have formatted already then check /media for your hard drive.

if this doesn't work go to terminal after plugging in the drive and type `lsusb` or `fdisk -l` and you should see your drive here with the name Western Digital or something of the like.

After this you can take 2 approaches, first is to just type `mount -a` and it should be mounted in /media/your-hard-disk and you should be able to access it.

second is to create a directory at /media with `mkdir /media/name` and use your result from the `fdisk -l` command here by typing `mount -t /dev/sdb1 /mount/name -o uid=1000,gid=1000,utf8,dmask=027,fmask=137` where sdb1 can be what you see in `fdisk -l` results.

if you have an error pop up with `mount -a` then edit it into your answer so i can help but do a simple search for the error because most likely there is a problem with your ubuntu which has already been discussed elsewhere.

Check here for more info: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Mount/USB

BTW: make sure that your drive is getting enough power if your ubuntu is installed on a different machine for windows. Hard drives are power hungry and do not start if they do not get ample power. After rereading your device i see that it is a laptop so this is possible, google for power issues with hard drives for more info about this issue

Answer (score -1):

It sounds like you may need to reformat you external hard drive.
It will be one of 2 format types but I can't remember which one you need of the top of my head.
It will either be FAT32 or NTFS.
When you format with windows it will give you a drop down menu.
Try both I think you need FAT32 but if this does not work try NTFS.
Good luck